# How to make Chrome view PDF in a new tab when I drag and drop it?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, browser-tabs, tabs

When I drag and drop pdfs into Chrome, they are opened, but they open in the same tab. If I want to have the pdf open in a new tab, I either have to right click -> Open with... or drag the pdf to the small + button that opens a new tab.

Is there any way I can make it so that the PDF will open in a new tab regardless of where it is dropped on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you drag the pdf anywhere in the topbar of chrome it'll open it in a new tab.

If you have many tabs open, just drag to an area above it (where the tabs don't extend) and you can even choose in between which two tabs to place it.

---

You can also leave a Chrome shortcut on your desktop and just drag to that icon.

Comment: This does not answer my question: I am aware if I drag it to a particular place it will open in a new tab. My question is asking is there a way to make it so that I /don't/ have to do that: i.e. regardless of whether I place it on an open tab, topbar, middle of the screen, etc. it will open in a new tab.

Comment: @NotAPro you wrote that you had to drag it to the **+**, I pointed out that you can drag it anywhere in the top tab bar.

Comment: Yes, that is true: but that doesn't answer my question. You should have posted that as a comment, not an answer.